# How do we avoid Cron jobs interruption?

Tags: parallel-processing, cron, google-cloud-platform

I am new at using Cron Jobs on Google Cloud: I was wondering if it is possible to launch a job on an instance and have it run continuously without interruption even after I shut down my local (Laptop). Is it possible to have a job running without any ssh connection?

Comment: What kind of instance (i.e. which GCP product)? Cron, in general, runs regardless of a user being logging in or not (regardless of the login method - SSH or something else).

Answer (score 0):

The CronJobs are a possibility, **but they are not meant to be used in your scenario**, but when you want to run a command with a certain frequency over the time.

A [Bash Builtin command](https://www.unix.com/man-page/all/1/disown/) that suits better your needs is `disown`. First, run your process/script in the background (using `&`, or stopping it with `^Z` and then restarting with `bg`):

```
$ long_operation_command &
[1] 1156
```

> Note that at this point the process is still linked to the session and in case it is closed it will be killed.
>   You can the process attached to the session check running `jobs` in the background:

```
$ jobs
[1]+  Running  long_operation_command
```

Therefore you can run disown in order to detach the processes from the session:

```
$ disown
```

You can confirm this checking the result of your script or command logging in again or checking with  `top` the process still running.

Check also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and?newreg=cb61c5c7450d45cebf32582e6ac5fd3e) because it could be interesting, i.e. the difference between `nohup foo`, `foo &` and `$ foo & disown`

P.S.
The direct answer to your question is yes, the cronjobs run even if you shutdown your laptop/shutdown the session.